# KeyExistsQ[] but for functions?

Tags: functions, variable-definitions

Is there a good way to check if, say, `f[5]` has been defined if `f` is a function, similar to `KeyExistsQ[f,5]` for associations? I want it to return false if `f[x_]` has a delayed assignment but `f[5]` in particular has not been assigned a value.

```
f[x_] := f[x] = x^2
KeyExistsForFunctionsQ[f,5]
f[5];
KeyExistsForFunctionsQ[f,5]
(*False, True*)
```

Comment: Have a look at `DownValues[f]` and `assoc = Association[Extract[#, {1, 1}, Hold] -> Extract[#, 2, Hold] & /@ DownValues[f]]` . It's then possible to check `KeyExistsQ[assoc, Hold[f[5]]]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple method for checking if any of the down values of a function matches `f[5]` literally. It's a good use case for `Verbatim`:

```
KeyExistsForFunctionsQ[fun_, arg_] := AnyTrue[
  Keys[DownValues[fun]],
  MatchQ[#, Verbatim[HoldPattern[fun[arg]]]] &
]
```

This method can be extended to checking other types of down values of functions as well. For example:

```
ValueQWithoutEval[fun_, arg_] := AnyTrue[
  Keys[DownValues[fun]],
  MatchQ[Hold[fun[arg]], Hold[#]] &
]
```

This will check if any of the down values of a function will match `fun[arg]` without actually trying to evaluate it (because it might be expensive, for example). Note that this will not work for assignments that use `Condition` in the r.h.s. of `:=` like

```
f[x_] := With[{y = 2 x + 1}, y /; PrimeQ[y]]
```

For functions like that, you can't avoid evaluating the function at least partially to find out if the argument matches.

Answer (score 9):

`DownValues` aren't the only method for caching previously computed results. For instance you can use an association,

```
ClearAll[fdata, f]
fdata = <||>;
f[x_] := Lookup[fdata, x, fdata[x] = x^2]
```

Now when you compute a value it is stored in `fdata`,

```
In[21]:= f /@ Range[3]

Out[21]= {1, 4, 9}

In[22]:= KeyExistsQ[fdata, #] & /@ Range[4]

Out[22]= {True, True, True, False}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[keyExistsQ]
keyExistsQ = Function[{func, arg}, 
   KeyExistsQ[DownValues[func], HoldPattern[func[arg]]], HoldAll];
```

***Example:***

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := f[x] = x^2

{keyExistsQ[f, 5], f[5], keyExistsQ[f, 5]}
```

> ```
> {False, 25, True}
> ```

Comment: As noted by Sjoerd in his answer  _this will not work for assignments that use `Condition` in the r.h.s._